# Use of "but" after "none"

Tags: conjunctions

In the quote below, please see the sentence that begins with the word "None." I have a question about the second half of this sentence. To understand it better, I paraphrased it to "none are so poor with a smile but they are richer for its benefits." I feel that the conjunction *but* is incorrect because it is not introducing an opposing idea. I think that *and* would be more preferable. I'm sure that the author knew English better than I do, so my thinking must be wrong. Would you please help me understand why I am wrong?

> The value of a smile... It costs nothing, but creates much. It enriches those who receive, without impoverishing those who give. It happens in a flash and the memory of it sometimes lasts forever. None are so rich they can get along without it, **and none so poor but are richer for its benefits.** It creates happiness in the home, fosters good will in a business, and is the countersign of friends.

—Dale Carnegie (2016), *How to Win Friends and Influence People*, p. 67, Diamond Pocket Books Pvt Ltd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "but" seems to be used in the sense of ["without its also being the case that"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/but#Conjunction). A second "they" has also been omitted, thus:

**and none so poor without its also being the case that [they] are richer for its benefits.**

Or to paraphrase even further:

**and none so poor that they aren't richer for its benefits.**

This use of but is very outdated. Of course the original version of the book is from 1936 and this part of it is supposed to be a poem.

Comment: I disagree that none .. but is obsolete. I think that the meaning is along these lines. There would be none, except for the example following. E.g:
None but he were present. None of the food was eatable but the bread and butter.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I also feel better to hear that the original book is very old.